# Receiving an error running script in local browser

Tags: javascript, html

Receiving error "Enabler is not defined" when I try and run the page on my local browser. Is there a reason the "Enabler" variable isn't active when it's called or is there a specific way I need to run this type of doc.

Thanks so much for your help!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <link type="text/css" href="styles.css"
    rel="stylesheet" />
  <script
    src="https://s0.2mdn.net/ads/studio/Enabler.js"></script>
  <script
    src="https://s0.2mdn.net/ads/studio/cached_libs/tweenmax_1.19.0_643d6911392a3398cb1607993edabfa7_min.js"></script>
  <script
    src="https://s0.2mdn.net/ads/studio/cached_libs/scrolltoplugin_1.19.0_53288c1da14a1784cdf302f94d0116a7_min.js"></script>
  <script
    src="https://s0.2mdn.net/ads/studio/cached_libs/textplugin_1.19.0_ee0a9b7420a65afd44a2fd958cd72d16_min.js"></script>
  <script src="mkr.min.js"></script>
  <script src="isi-ss-tool.js"></script>
  <script src="banner.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var clickTag1 = 'https://zilrettapro.com/request-a-rep-email-sign-up/';
    var clickTag2 = 'https://zilrettalabel.com/PI.pdf';
    var clickTag3 = 'https://www.fda.gov/medwatch';

    function activateClickTags() {
      mkr.on('#cta', 'click', linkHandler);
      mkr.on('#pi', 'click', linkHandler);
      mkr.on('#fda', 'click', linkHandler);
    }

    function linkHandler(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      switch (e.target.id) {
        case 'cta':
          Enabler.exit('CTA Exit', clickTag1);
          break;
        case 'pi':
          Enabler.exit('PI Exit', clickTag2);
          break;
        case 'fda':
          Enabler.exit('FDA Exit', clickTag3);
          break;
      }
      return false;
    }

    window.onload = function () {
      //Polite loadind...
      if (Enabler.isInitialized()) {
        initHandler();
      } else {
        Enabler.addEventListener(studio.events.StudioEvent.INIT, initHandler);
      }
    };
  </script>
</head>
```

Comment: DON'T use the `script` tag. Every SO question is about scripts one way or another. It's no better than adding `code` as a tag. That tag is just noise, it was deleted in the past and will be deleted very soon again.